# Plot straight lines with pgfplots using polaraxis with legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, polarplot

I am trying to plot straight lines in the `polaraxis` environment (which is a requirement). Since they **must pass by the origin**, the parametric polar equation is of the form `$\theta=constant$`. However, in `pgfplots`, it seems that one can only describe the plot as `$r=f(\theta)$` (with the usual notations for the radius and angle in polar coordinates).

A way to circumvent that would be to use `draw` as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        no marks,samples=1000,xmin=0,xmax=90,ymin=0,ymax=1,xtick = {0,22.5,45,68.5},xticklabels={,,},ytick={0,1},
        major tick length=0pt,legend style={at={(0.9,0.9)},font=\footnotesize},
        yticklabel style={anchor=north}
        ] 
        \addplot[domain=-1:0.2, data cs = polarrad,draw=blue, thick]   {0.01*exp(x/0.031)};
        \addlegendentry{blue legend}
        \draw[red,thick] (0,0) -- (100,200);
        \addlegendentry{red legend}
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My blue curve is my existing `pgfplots` curve, working properly with legend. In red is a straight line I am **trying to associate a legend with**, which doesn't work with this code (problem of compatibility tiks vs pgfplots?).

Another solution that I tried first was to use the `xticks`, plotted here for angles `{0,22.5,45,68.5}`; but the same issue holds that I can't associate a legend to the ticks seeding from the origin and forming the required straight lines.

I must be missing a simple trick as it shouldn't be a big task.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a compilable MWE(Minimal Working Example) showing a single plot and a `\draw` of the desired line.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, hoping it's fine now.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should alway set the compat level - see code. In new versions of PGFPlots, the axis coordinates are used inside the `axis`. I changed `(100,200)` to a line at 60 degrees: `(1:60)` (same as `(60,1)`). Here is how to just add an extra legend entry:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        no marks,samples=1000,xmin=0,xmax=90,ymin=0,ymax=1,xtick = {0,22.5,45,68.5},xticklabels={,,},ytick={0,1},
        major tick length=0pt,legend style={at={(0.9,0.9)},font=\footnotesize},
        yticklabel style={anchor=north}
        ] 
        \addplot[domain=-1:0.2, data cs = polarrad,draw=blue, thick]   {0.01*exp(x/0.031)};
        \addlegendentry{ blue legend};
        \draw[red,thick] (0,0) -- (1:60);
        \addlegendimage{line legend, red, thick};
        \addlegendentry{red legend};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Polar plot with blue and red line]

and to use `\addplot` :

```
  \addplot[red, thick] coordinates{(0,0) (60,1)};
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, that solves my problem!